# EmberJS Cannot set property 'store' of undefined (DS.hasMany)

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data, ember-app-kit

Firstly I have read the related issues on SO and none seem to help me.

I have 2 models, **Foo** and **Bar**. **Foo** has a property, **bars**, which **hasMany** **Bar**.

// FOO

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  bars: hasMany('bar')
});
```

// BAR

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string')
  foo: belongsTo('foo')
});
```

And the JSON payload:

```
{
  "name": "Something",
  "bars": [
    {
       "name": "something else"
    },
    {
       "name": "another one"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've been trying to figure this error out for a while but I am stuck.

Here is the [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pohafata/3/edit?html,js,console).
If you look in the browsers console (not the jsbin one) you can see the error.

Comment: Could you please demo this on http://emberjs.jsbin.com?

Comment: I edited the question with the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not specifying an ID for your "bar" objects. Each model needs an ID to make the object unque and know how to relate that to a resource. Changing your server output to the following should solve the issue:

```
{
  "name": "Something",
  "bars": [
    {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "something else"
    },
    {
       "id": 2,   
       "name": "another one"
    }
  ]
}
```

Another solution (IDs should really be there regardless) is to set "async" to true as follows:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  bars: hasMany('bar', { async: true })
});
```

This will cause EmberJS to load the data in the background and not block/causes errors with anything waiting on relationship resoltion.